# Reschedule failed jobs in hangfire

Tags: hangfire

Is it possible to reschedule failed jobs in hangfire? And Is there any way to clear the failed job queue after the success?

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Jobs will be cleared automatically by hangfire after one day (by default).
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-configure-the-retention-time-of-job/34/2?u=odinserj

See hangfire documentation about dealing with exceptions occurs during jobs execution

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/dealing-with-exceptions.html

Comment: "Jobs will be cleared automatically by hangfire after one day"

Note that this is not the case for failed jobs. By default, these are kept indefinitely until retried or manually removed. Only succesful and deleted jobs are cleared as such.